# How to serialize Instant field of class with swagger-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-maven-plugin

I have class with the field:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Дата получения баланса", example = "2018-01-16T09:22:33.316Z")
@JsonProperty("date")
private Instant date;
```

When I generate yaml from this source (with swagger-maven-plugin) I get:

```
date:
    type: "integer"
    format: "int64"
    example: "2018-01-16T09:22:33.316Z"
    description: "Дата получения баланса"
```

So when I generate back my class from yaml (with swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) I get it with field:

```
@JsonProperty("date")
private Long date = null;
```

Why Instant converts to Long?

Comment: In first place why from "private Instant date;' you get 'type: "integer"'?

Comment: @lczapski  excactly!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of swaggger-core, and it was fixed on version 2.1.2 (See [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/pull/3477)).

If you're using a previous version you can customize this behaviour by replacing the PrimitiveType for the Instant data type with the following snippet:

```
PrimitiveType.customClasses().put(java.time.Instant.class.getName(), 
                              PrimitiveType.DATE_TIME);
```